# Why can't massive nuclei combine together to release energy

Tags: nuclear-physics, stability, binding-energy, elements

I am basically confused as why can't larger nuclei undergo fushion and release energy. One reason I know is because of too much protons than neutrons which generates stronger electrostatic repulsive forces.But another reason is something related to binding energy per nucleon which is making it difficult for me to understand.

Comment: While this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/215769) isn't exactly the same, the comment has some good links to similar questions that deal with the fact that iron is a natural stopping point for fusion.